# How to implement poly1d in C++ via OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I know the function of `polyfit` is a line-fitting function that returns a "y=ax+b" line to fit the given points, in Python.

In C++, I use the OpenCV function `fitLine`, which returns a line presented by 4 parameters((vx, vy, x0, y0), where (vx, vy) is a normalized vector collinear to the line and (x0, y0) is a point on the line.).

But I cannot understand the `poly1d` function. And I cannot implement it by OpenCV and C++.

How could I do to implement `poly1d` and use the return values from `fitLine` function ?

```
lineModel = np.poly1d(np.polyfit([y1, y2], [x1, x2], 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is a bit off the question asked but you can use `polyfit` if you are using earlier version of `openCV`. I used it for `openCV 2.4.13`. It can be used to get coefficients of any order fit. Beware the coefficients are returned in reverse order.

```
float xData[] = { 0.0f,1.0f ,2.0f,3.0f  };
float yData[] = { 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, };
int order = 1;

Mat out = Mat(order + 1, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat x1 = Mat(3, 1, CV_32F, xData);
Mat y2 = Mat(3, 1, CV_32FC1, yData);

polyfit(x1, y2, out, order);
```